# MySQL missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create some tables in MySQL and am getting an error that I cannot find an answer to on here. Here are the tables I'm trying to create (indented for readability):

```
CREATE TABLE Journal (ISSN INT NOT NULL, ChiefEditor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 JournalTitle VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ISSN)); 

CREATE TABLE Volume (Year INT NOT NULL, ISSN INT NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY(Year, ISSN), FOREIGN KEY (ISSN) REFERENCES Journal(ISSN));

CREATE TABLE Edition (Month INT NOT NULL, Year INT NOT NULL, ISSN INT NOT NULL, 
 FirstPage INT, LastPage INT, PRIMARY KEY(Month, Year, ISSN), 
 FOREIGN KEY (Year, ISSN) REFERENCES Volume(Year, ISSN)); 

CREATE TABLE Article (FirstPage INT NOT NULL, LastPage INT NOT NULL, Month INT NOT NULL, 
 Year INT NOT NULL, ISSN INT NOT NULL, ArticleTitle VARCHAR(50), Abstract VARCHAR(1000), 
 PDFPath VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(FirstPage, LastPage, Month, Year, ISSN), 
 FOREIGN KEY (Month, Year, ISSN) REFERENCES Edition(Month, Year, ISSN));

CREATE TABLE User (Email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, Title VARCHAR(15), Forename VARCHAR(20), 
 Surname VARCHAR(30), University VARCHAR(30), Password VARCHAR(40),
 IsEditor BOOLEAN, IsAuthor BOOLEAN, IsReviewer BOOLEAN, PRIMARY KEY(Email));

CREATE TABLE ArticleAuthor (Email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ISSN INT NOT NULL,
 Month INT NOT NULL, Year INT NOT NULL, FirstPage INT NOT NULL, LastPage INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(Email, ISSN, Month, Year, FirstPage, LastPage), FOREIGN KEY (Email)
 REFERENCES User(Email), FOREIGN KEY (ISSN, Month, Year, FirstPage, LastPage)
 REFERENCES Article(ISSN, Month, Year, FirstPage, LastPage));
```

When I run this code, MySQL displays:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'articleauthor_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'article'

The problematic tables seem to be ArticleAuthor and Author, but the others are included just in case.

I've looked on here and most answers suggested either there is a type mismatch between primary/foreign keys or that the references I'm trying to make are to fields that are not unique. However, all the types seem to match and I believe I'm only referencing primary key fields which surely are implicitly unique? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of making other people figure  out where the error is coming from, why don't you just make it clear?

Comment: I included the error message text and pointed towards the tables that I think are causing the problem - if you have any suggestions for ways to make it clearer please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary key for article is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (FirstPage, LastPage, Month, Year, ISSN)
```

The foreign key reference is:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ISSN, Month, Year, FirstPage, LastPage)
```

These columns are not in the same order.  They need to be in the same order.

That said, 5-part composite primary keys seem like a database nightmare.  Introduce an auto-incremented `articleId` and just use:

```
FOREIGN KEY (articleId) REFERENCES articles (articleId)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. And thanks for the tip re automatically incrementing IDs - the brief specifies that those five fields combined are what identify each article, but I'm guessing there aren't any situations where they cannot be identified by the ID instead?

Comment: Of course the five identifying columns stay in the original table.  However, foreign key references can just refer to one column -- which is simpler in many respects.

Comment: If I understand correctly, foreign keys can only reference primary keys in the table they reference - so if I were to redesign my 'nested' tables (journals have volumes, which have editions etc) to use IDs instead of their current composite keys, surely I would no longer be able to reference fields such as ISSN. In this case, would it make more sense to retrieve this information via a join when querying, so it doesn't have to be 'passed down' the series of nested tables? Hopefully that made sense! Trying to wrap my head around dependencies etc